# How to make the proxy connection close when served in firefox?

Tags: firefox-3.6, http-proxy

It seems by default its proxy connection `keep-alive` as the header states:

```
Keep-Alive: 300
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type about:config in the address bar. change this value to false.

```
network.http.proxy.keep-alive
```

Comment: Although keep in mind this is more or less an obsolete setting as of http 1.1